# spring-mvc intro and example - vim, tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm looking for a good intro or getting started tutorial or example for the latest Spring-MVC.   I prefer (at least for now anyway) not to use any Java IDE such as Eclipse as I love using Vim.  I want to keep it simple.   Would be great if the example used Tomcat too but I'm open.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at http://spring.io/guides

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for the book: Spring in Action